# How to send the data from the current activity to the previous activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've created two activities. The first accepts the name of a student through an edit text and has a submit button. When the submit button is pressed, the next activity opens which has an edit text (to accept the marks) along with a back button.

I wish to return the marks entered to the first activity, when the back button of second activity is pressed so that the marks are displayed in the first edit text.

Kindly provide me  with the code for the two activities.

Comment: Sorry SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: If you already created the activities, you should provide the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use activity for result . An example is given [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

Comment: Although the question doesn't belong to SO your answer is of very low quality. Why should the OP "use activity for result"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Hello *Akanksha Gahalout*, if i understand your question, you want to pass Data between two activities and vice versa , if so, you should use **Intent** and use **PutExtrat()** method to pass data from one Activity to another,then you can recuperate data from the second Activity with using **Bundle** and **getExtras()** method.

*Here's an example :*

**FirstActivity.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextFirstActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/StudentName"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:labelFor="@+id/EditText1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFirstActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OK" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewFirstActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FirstActivity.java :**

```
package dz.A;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editTextFirstActivity;
    private Button buttonFirstActivity;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);
        editTextFirstActivity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFirstActivity);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewFirstActivity);
        buttonFirstActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFirstActivity);
        buttonFirstActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent iin = getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if (b != null) {
            String marks = (String) b.get("STUDENT_MARKS");
            textView.setText(marks);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonFirstActivity) {
            Log.i("OK", "onClickOK");
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            Log.i("OK", "IntentOK");
            Log.i("OK", "startActivity(i)OK");
            String studentName = editTextFirstActivity.getText().toString()
                    .trim();
            Log.i("OK", "studentNameOK : " + studentName);
            i.putExtra("STUDENT_NAME", "Student Name : " + studentName);
            Log.i("OK", "i.putExtraOK");
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            Log.i("OK", "finish()OK");

        }

    }


}
```

**SecondActivity.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextSecondActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/Marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:labelFor="@+id/EditText1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSecondActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sendMarks" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewSecondActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.java :**

```
package dz.A;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView textViewSecondActivity;
    private EditText editTextSecondActivity;
    private Button buttonSecondActivity;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        textViewSecondActivity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewSecondActivity);
        editTextSecondActivity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSecondActivity);
        buttonSecondActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSecondActivity);
        buttonSecondActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent iin = getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if (b != null) {
            String studentName = (String) b.get("STUDENT_NAME");
            textViewSecondActivity.setText(studentName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonSecondActivity) {
            String marks = editTextSecondActivity.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("STUDENT_MARKS", "Student Marks : " + marks);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dz.A"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="dz.A.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity  android:name="dz.A.SecondActivity"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**String.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Project</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="OK">OK</string>
    <string name="Marks">Marks</string>
    <string name="sendMarks">sendMarks</string>
    <string name="StudentName">StudentName</string>

</resources>
```

I hope that helps you.